# Почему запросы в БД отправляются дважды при загрузке страницы, вместо одного?

Tags: reactjs, axios, асинхронность, useeffect

Необходимо получить данные из базы данных **MongoDb** прямо при загрузке страницы для дальнейшего использования.

Я пытался сделать это примерно так:

```
const [api,setApi] = useState(null)
const [settings, setSettings] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        let queriesList = ['/api/get_api_data','/api/get_settings']
        let allInfo = await Promise.all(queriesList.map(async q => {
            return await axios.post(q)
        }))
        setApi(allInfo[0].data)
        setSettings(allInfo[1].data)
    })()
}, [setApi,setSettings])
```

Как сделать это грамотно, а не так, как получилось?)

**Ещё проблема заключается в том, что при загрузке страницы, запросы отправляются дважды.**

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы запрос отправлялся 1 раз при загрузке страницы(компонента), необходимо в хуке **useEffect**, в качестве зависимостей передать пустой массив.

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const send = (url) => {
      let result;
      await axios.post(url)
        .then( res => {
          // Тут бы не плохо добавить проверки
          result = res[0].data;
        })
        .catch(rej => {
          // Что от обработать
          result = {} // Для примера
        })
      return result;
    };
    setApi(await send('/api/get_api_data'));
    setSettings(await send('/api/get_settings'));
}, []); // <-- Вот тут
```

Данных хук будет срабатывать только один раз в момент первичной установки компонента в **DOM** дерево. Это аналог [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)